# CSS animation only display on first slide image

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to make few images displaying as slides with fadeIn effect in css. Everything works fine, images are displayed in 3s period with setInterval javascript method, but only first image displays with fadeIn animation.

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 66vw;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="slide" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/components/global/search-explore-nav/img/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d941529c25aa511dc18d727160.jpg">
```

There is only one jpg added to HTML and javascript code is written to replace file path from

```
 <img class="slide" src="1.JPG">
```

to "2.jpg", "3.jpg" etc

Only first image has animation, everything displayed later is without animation.

When I check console, all next images still have .slide class and all its properties position/width/height/animation, but they display without animation.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve]

Comment: Since you're just changing the attributes (namely `src`) of the `img`, but you don't replace the element itself, the animation won't run again.

Comment: Couldnt load my js code, something went wrong. Sorry mplungjan, i will try to practise next time before posting. And thanks FZs for reply, i will try to add all images to html then and relace whole element.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to trigger the `css` animation every time you change the `src`. You can do it by removing the element class, triggering a DOM reflow, and adding the class again. But you should be careful because triggering reflow can be an expensive operation. Read more about it [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/web-performance-dom-reflow-76ac7c4d2d4f).

```js
const images = [
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=image1",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=image2",
  "https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=image3",
];

const img = document.querySelector(".slide");

let imageIndex = 0;
const imageInterval = setInterval(() => {
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= images.length) {
    clearInterval(imageInterval);
  } else {
    img.src = images[imageIndex];

    img.classList.remove("slide");
    void img.offsetWidth; // trigger a DOM reflow
    img.classList.add("slide");
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 66vw;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300?text=image1">
```

Comment: yes, that exactly what i want. Thanks a lot for reply, will try to mess with code and make it work

Comment: @sasax Glad that it helped, you can also mark it as answered if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you want but with pure CSS perhaps something like this

```css
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 66vw;
  animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}
.two {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.three {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="slide" src="https://static.vecteezy.com/packs/media/components/global/search-explore-nav/img/vectors/term-bg-1-666de2d941529c25aa511dc18d727160.jpg">
<img class="slide two" src="https://compote.slate.com/images/f063a07e-e5ab-4e04-8093-281d0a28ebe8.jpeg">
<img class="slide three" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nWLUdoK5fSs/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: that is exactly what i want ! but my code only shows first image with animation. will try your way, thanks a lot